# ¿Como devolver los valores de las columnas pares al cubo?

Tags: java, bucle-for, bucles, matrices

Estoy atascado en este ejercicio, el enunciado es el siguiente:

> Crear un programa que llene una matriz 5x3 con valores entre -100 y
> 100. Luego, en otra matriz del mismo tamaño, guarde los valores almacenados en la primera matriz elevando al cubo los almacenados en
> columnas pares y elevando al cuadrado los almacenados en columnas
> impares.

Esto es lo que he realizado:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Random r=new Random();
    
    final int FILAS=5;
    final int COLUMNAS=3;
    int [][]miMatriz=new int[FILAS][COLUMNAS];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < FILAS; i++) {                                      //bucle para meter aleatorios
        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNAS; j++) {
            miMatriz[i][j]=r.nextInt(201)-100;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < FILAS; i++) {                                      //recorro
        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNAS; j++) {
            System.out.print(miMatriz[i][j]+ "\t");  
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    
    
    
    double [][]miMatriz2=new double[miMatriz.length][miMatriz[0].length];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < miMatriz2.length; i++) {                            //copia del otro array, pero double
        for (int j = 0; j < miMatriz2[0].length; j++) {
            miMatriz2[i][j]=miMatriz[i][j];
        }
    }   
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < miMatriz2.length; i++) {                                       //recorro el nuevo para comprobar valores
        for (int j = 0; j < miMatriz2[0].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(miMatriz2[i][j]+ "\t");  
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    
    System.out.println();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < miMatriz2.length; i++) {            //aquí ya voy perdido
        for (int j = 0; j < miMatriz2[0].length; j++) {
            if (j%2==0) {
                miMatriz[i][j]=Math.pow(miMatriz[j], 3);
            }
        }
    }



}

}
```

Comment: Según lo que entiendo, te hace falta llenar la segunda matriz con el valor actualizado de la primera, en este caso como ya identificaste la columna par, solo faltaría hacer `miMatriz2[i][j]=Math.pow(miMatriz[i][j], 3);` y en la sección del else `miMatriz2[i][j]=Math.pow(miMatriz[i][j], 2);`, al final recorres `miMatriz2` para ver los resultados

Answer (score 0):

Debes tener en cuenta que en Java los arreglos se inicializan en 0

```
for(int i = 0; i<Filas;i++)
{
   for(int j = 0; j< columnas;j++)
   {
      if((j+1)%2 == 0)
      {
         matrizB[i,j] = Math.pow(matrizA[i,j],3);
      }
      else
      {
         matrizB[i,j] = Math.pow(matrizA[i,j],2);
      }
   }
}
```

Recorro la matriz con dos ciclos y pregunto si la posición actual + 1 es par o impar, le suma + 1 ya que para nosotros la primera posición no es la 0 sino la 1, los humanos no empezamos contando a partir de 0 sino de 1, si es par guardo en esa posición en la segunda matriz el cubo de esa posición de la primera matriz, si es impar pues guardo el cuadrado

Answer (score 0):

muchas gracias por responder y por la rapidez, me habéis sido de gran ayuda. Aunque a mi al hacer el j+1 me cambiaba los pares por impares. Pero en otros casos si he tenido que hacer el j+1 por lo de las posiciones en java.
Al final me ha funcionado así:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < FILAS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNAS; j++) {
            if (j%2==0) {
                miMatriz2[i][j]=Math.pow(miMatriz2[i][j],3);
            }else {
                miMatriz2[i][j]=Math.pow(miMatriz2[i][j],2);
            }
            
            System.out.print(miMatriz2[i][j]+ "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: El j+1 te lo puse pq las personas empezamos contando a partir del 1,  aquí tu estas asumiendo que la primera posición es la 0, igual lo hiciste bien, es un problema de enfoque saludos